# Why there is a difference between drawing in TikZEdt and usual compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

These are output of my figures in `TikZEdt` and usual compiling:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\draw  (-4,4.6) rectangle (3,-5.6);
\draw[->,thick] (-4,-5.9) node[below]{$t=0$}node[below=.2cm,right=4.38cm]{$t=0$}-- (-4,5.1)node[above]{$x$};
 \draw[->,thick]  (-4.6,-0.5) -- (4,-0.5)node[right]{$t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Output:** Using `Textstudio` through `pdflatex`:

### [image]

Using `TikZEdt`

[image]

> Why the outputs differ? what is the good way for placing these two `t=0` in the same line?

Comment: I think it doesn't depend on the editor but on the preamble, please complete your MWE

Comment: If I use `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in the texstudio preamble I get the same result as TikzEdt.

Comment: @vipa- You are right. How to place these two `t=0` in the same horizontal  line? Why `node[below=.2cm,right=4.38cm]` isn't work in presence of `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`?